# atlas-run-standalone --product jira, this command blocks development

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

```
.
.
.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 6.x started on port [2990]
[INFO] jira started successfully in 249s at http://localhost:2990/jira
[INFO] Type Ctrl-D to shutdown gracefully
[INFO] Type Ctrl-C to exit
```

but it is not letting me use other commands in command prompt.how to get out of it without shutting down service?

Comment: It's running as a foreground process when invoked like that, so it's doing what it is supposed to. What is wrong with opening another command prompt? If you want a background process, you're better off downloading a jira-standalone install.

Comment: @ScottDudley I actually tried opening another command prompt, but it was running same instance on windows 8.1 os.But i figured it out  and opened another command prompt.I wish if everything was done same command prompt.Thanks.